# How to check the health of the Azure Log Analytics REST API

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have an application that uses [Azure Log Analytics REST API](https://dev.loganalytics.io/) to query logs data from Azure log analytics workspace. I want to implement a public health check endpoint for that application. That health check ideally should assess the connection to the Log Analytics REST API and confirm the status of it. So is there a public health check endpoint available for Azure Log Analytics REST API? If not how can I achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the status of the [REST API](https://dev.loganalytics.io/), just take use of this api with any program language. For example, there is always a table named `AzureActivity`, you can use this api to query this table, if the response is returned with 200 status code, then it means this api or Log Analytics workspace is available.

Note: Please replace the `DEMO_WORKSPACE` and `DEMO_KEY` with the real one.

Here is the screenshot about how to use this api, you can use it with any program language:

[image]

Comment: @Madusha, hello, can you please mark it as answer(not up-vote) if it helps? As per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top), thank you:)

Comment: Marked as the answe :)